# Solving for the function $x(t)$ in the differential equation $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{3}{2}C\left[\frac{\sqrt{A}}{x}+\sqrt{B}\right]dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm a little stumped on something I'm working on. I have an expression in this following form:

> $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{3}{2}C\left[\frac{\sqrt{A}}{x}+\sqrt{B}\right]dt$$

I was essentially wondering how I go about solving this for $x$ explicitly.

I'm perhaps thinking I might need to make a substitution which may involve a $\sinh$ function?

Help!

Comment: Divide both sides by the term in bracket and integrate.

Comment: Of course, that's so simple! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This equation is separable: By dividing both sides by the quantity in brackets, we get
$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{A} + \sqrt{B} x} = \frac{3}{2}C \,dt.$$
We can integrate the l.h.s. using the substitution $u = \sqrt{A} + \sqrt{B} x$, $du = \sqrt{B} dx$, and it's easy to invert the resulting equation to give $x$ as a function of $t$. (The constant of parameterization leads to a one-parameter family of solutions.) NB that this technique omits a single solution, corresponding to when the divided quantity is identically zero.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the expression

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac32 C\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}}{x}+\sqrt{B}\right)\,dt$$

we divide both sides by $\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}}{x}+\sqrt{B}\right)$ and integrate to find

$$\int \frac{1}{x\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}}{x}+\sqrt{B}\right)}\,dx=\frac32 C\int (1)\,dt$$

Thus, we obtain

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt B}\,\log\left(\sqrt A+\sqrt B x\right)=\frac32 C\,t+K$$

whereupon solving for $t$ yields

$$t=\frac2{3C\sqrt B}\log\left(\sqrt A+\sqrt B x\right)+K'$$

Comment: Hi @Dr.MV This is the result I obtained too. However, my lecturer is asking for the expression as x(t)=...sinh(RHS)...I'm just lost/puzzled as to where a sinh would come from for this?

Comment: If we invert the expression for $t$, we end up with an exponential function.  - Mark

Comment: Of course, taking the exponent of both sides and we can re-arranged for x(t). But how then do we get to hyperbolic sine functions with an exponent on the RHS?

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = Dx + E$ with $D,E$ can be determined from the equation, and you have a linear $1$st order ODE which you have learned and can solve.